# How to control service Execution order in service fabric applicationManifest or serviceManifest?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

In my `ServiceManifest.xml`, I have two code packages: the first code package has one setup entry point **A** and one entry point **B**

```
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0">
<SetupEntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>A.bat</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>
<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>B.exe</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>Work</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
</CodePackage>
```

The second code package one entry point **c**:

```
<CodePackage Name="anotherCode" Version="1.0">
<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>C.exe</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>Work</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
</CodePackage>
```

I want to the start order is A> B > C, that means B will be executed after A succeeds, C will be executed after B succeeds. Now A will executed first, due to A is under . but I don't know how to control the order of B and C.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the exact purpose of this chain of execution, but what you are trying to do does not work.

**SetupEntryPoint** is meant to execute as an initialization script in order to setup the environment for the main program(executable) to start, things like create folders, install dependencies, copy data and so on. It is a privileged entry point that by default runs with the same credentials as Service Fabric (typically the NETWORKSERVICE account) before any other entry point. The *SetupEntryPoint* avoids having to run the service host with high privileges for extended periods of time.

**EntryPoint** is the main program(executable) that will be always running when a service is created, it is not meant to complete(stop) until requested by service fabric, if it does stop, service fabric will take it as a failure an start it again.

**CodePackage**s are meant to join multiple programs(executables) as a single service within the service package,  When a service is instantiated against one of these service types, all code packages declared in the manifest are activated by running their entry points. Generally used in scenarios where you are two executables that must be running at same time on same node, an example is the main application and a log collector or a watchdog app monitoring the main application. When one application starts, the full package will be copied to the node and the code packages activated.

If you are trying to create a chain of execution, you should either:

- Create a service to keep this control and create(start) and delete(stop) these packages on demand, or
- Create a script as an entry point that keep running these executable after previously  has completed